# Can't exit the while loop after guessing the right number

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to make a simple number guessing program with while loop but even after finding the right number (I changed the num with 5 and it didn't work) it does not exit the while loop. Can you tell me where the problem is?

```
int guess;
int num;

cout << "Enter the number (0-10): ";
cin >> guess;

while(guess != num){
    int num = rand()%10;
    cout << "Nope, keep trying." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number (0-10): ";
    cin >> guess;
}

cout << "Congrats, you've found the number!" << endl;
```

Comment: It is worth noting that in the `while (guess != num)` check, you are reading the value of `num` when it is not initialized. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you deliberately changing the number they're trying to guess every time they make a guess?

Comment: As written, guessing the same number (say, 5) over and over again is exactly as good a strategy as guessing a different number each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int num = rand() % 10;` is a declaration of a new variable `num` within the loop body and that *shadows* the `num` defined at the top of the program: `while (guess != num)` is using the latter.

The solution is to write `num = rand() % 10;` instead.

You will need to *initialise* `num` to a value before attempting to read it, else technically the behaviour of your program is *undefined*. Consider reworking to a `do` `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, this was an obvious mistake. After deleting the "int" in loop it worked. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is evaluating a `num` variable that is never assigned a value. The assignment being done inside the loop is to a different `num` variable that *shadows* the outer variable of the same name.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int guess;
    int num;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the number (0-10): ";
        if (cin >> guess) {
            if (guess == num)
                break;
            num = rand() % 10;
            cout << "Nope, keep trying." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Not a number, keep trying." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    cout << "Congrats, you've found the number!" << endl;
}
```